# Tippy.JS "TypeError: instance.setContent is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tippyjs

When I try to set the content of a tooltip in Tippy.JS, I get the error `TypeError: instance.setContent is not a function`.

This is my code:

```
var instance = tippy('#range', {
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: '',
});

$('#range').on('input', function () {
    instance.setContent('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: have you included the files of tippy.js?

Comment: I did, it's referenced above my javascript file

Answer (score 1):

As *weird* as it may be, tippy returns an ARRAY no matter what type of selector you use. That is because the tippy function can return multiple items depending on the selector.
eg.

```
tippy("[notice='tippy']",{
            theme:'light',
            allowHTML:true,
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: contentElement.innerHTML,
            animation:'scale-subtle',
            trigger:'click',
            interactive: true,
            maxWidth: "none",
            allowHTML:true,
            onShow(instance) {
                instance.setContent(contentElement.innerHTML);
                this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            }
        })
```

The above code selects all elements with the attribute notice with value 'tippy' and return an array of Tippy Instances

```
[{/*Tippy Object*/},{/*Tippy Object*/}] //Javascript Array of Objects
```

If your sure only one element will be returned I suggest you use [0] to return only that one element in the array.

```
let oneTippy = tippy("#tippyElement",{
            theme:'light',
            allowHTML:true,
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: contentElement.innerHTML,
            animation:'scale-subtle',
            trigger:'click',
            interactive: true,
            maxWidth: "none",
            allowHTML:true,
            onShow(instance) {
                instance.setContent(contentElement.innerHTML);
                this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            }
        })[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

instance[0].setProps({content: 'Hello World!'})

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.